# How to repeat an HTML code with input and with a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to repeat a container n times by pressing a button. The container contains an input Box that a has JS function. I tried to create a "virtual" DOM to repeat the code using document.createElement() with the target code stored in a variable "pageHTML", but it only works with the html code. It doesn't work when I include the '< script>' tag. I'm just a beginner I hope someone could help me for my project. Thanks

Here's my sample code:

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="inputContainer">
        <p>Name: </p>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="DisplayInputText()">
    </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">Repeat Container</button>

<script>
    function DisplayInputText() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }


    var pageHtml = '<html><body><div class="container"><p>Name: </p><input type="text" 
        id="myInput" oninput="DisplayInputText()"></div>'
        + '<script>function DisplayInputText() {'
        + 'var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;'
        + 'document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;}'
        + '</script></body></html>';

    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var newPage = document.createElement('div');
        newPage.id = "newMyDiv";
        newPage.innerHTML = pageHtml;

        document.body.appendChild(newPage);
    })

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With js if you use an ID as identifier, you can only have 1 element since the ID must be unique.

If you want the same function to get applied to more element, you can use a class to identify the elements.

So then you don't need to repeat the function with the same ID, wich is going to lead to an error